# Silverstripe Site Search for DataObjects as Pages - Part 2 tutorial

Tags: php, search, silverstripe

I made a product site at the end of last year using [DataObjects as Pages - Part 2](http://www.ssbits.com/tutorials/2010/dataobjects-as-pages-part-2-using-model-admin-and-url-segments-to-create-a-product-catalogue/) Silverstripe, the site is live now, and I need to implement a site search function for the site.

I implemented a search function like [Tutorial 4 - Site Search](http://doc.silverstripe.org/sapphire/en/tutorials/4-site-search) however this doesn't work with the product search since each product is a dataobject rather than a page.

Can anyone shed some light on how I can make the site search work for the products?

I know there is a [tutorial 3 DataObject as Pages](http://www.ssbits.com/tutorials/2012/dataobject-as-pages-the-module/) I tried it but it messed up all my existing products as well as some additional existing functions for the products. Someone suggested http://silverstripe.org/all-other-modules/show/6641?start=24  but unsuccessful so far.

Any help on how to do the search function for the products is appreciated.

Thanks.

Here is my `Product.php` code

```php
<?php

class Product extends DataObject
{
    static $db = array(
        'Title' => 'Varchar(255)',
        'Description' => 'HTMLText',
        'Price' => 'Decimal(6,2)',
        'URLSegment' => 'Varchar(255)'
    );

    //Set our defaults
    static $defaults = array(  
        'Title' => 'New Product',
        'URLSegment' => 'new-product'
    );

    static $has_one = array(
        'Image' => 'Image',
        'PDF' => 'File' 
    );

    //Relate to the category pages
    static $belongs_many_many = array(
        'Categories' => 'CategoryPage'
    );

    //Fields to show in ModelAdmin table
    static $summary_fields = array(
        'Title' => 'Title',
        'URLSegment' => 'URLSegment',
        'Price' => 'Price (&pound;)'
    ); 

    //Add an SQL index for the URLSegment
    static $indexes = array(
        "URLSegment" => true
    );  

    //Fields to search in ModelAdmin
    static $searchable_fields = array (
        'Title',
        'URLSegment',
        'Description',
        'Categories.ID' => array(
            'title' => 'Category'
        )
    );


    function getCMSFields()
    {

        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        //Main Tab
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new TextField('Title', 'Title'));   
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new TextField('URLSegment', 'URL Segment'));
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new NumericField('Price'));
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new HTMLEditorField('Description'));

        //added below for the ordering
        $Categories = DataObject::get('CategoryPage');
        $map = $Categories->map('ID', 'CheckboxSummary');
        asort($map);
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Categories", new CheckboxsetField('Categories', 'Categories', $map));

        //Images
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Images", new ImageField('Image', 'Image', Null, Null, Null, 'Uploads/category_banners'));

        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Files", new FileIFrameField('PDF'));

        return $fields;
    }

    //Set URLSegment to be unique on write
    function onBeforeWrite()
    {      
        // If there is no URLSegment set, generate one from Title
        if((!$this->URLSegment || $this->URLSegment == 'new-product') && $this->Title != 'New Product')
        {
            $this->URLSegment = SiteTree::generateURLSegment($this->Title);
        }
        else if($this->isChanged('URLSegment'))
        {
            // Make sure the URLSegment is valid for use in a URL
            $segment = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/','-',$this->URLSegment);
            $segment = preg_replace('/-+/','-',$segment);

            // If after sanitising there is no URLSegment, give it a reasonable default
            if(!$segment) {
                $segment = "product-$this->ID";
            }

            $this->URLSegment = $segment;

        }


        // Ensure that this object has a non-conflicting URLSegment value.
        $count = 2;
        while($this->LookForExistingURLSegment($this->URLSegment))
        {

            $this->URLSegment = preg_replace('/-[0-9]+$/', null, $this->URLSegment) . '-' . $count;
            $count++;

        }

        parent::onBeforeWrite();

    }

    //Test whether the URLSegment exists already on another Product
    function LookForExistingURLSegment($URLSegment)
    {

        return (DataObject::get_one('Product', "URLSegment = '" . $URLSegment ."' AND ID != " . $this->ID));

    }


    //Generate the link for this product

    function Link()
    {
        //if we are on a category page return that
        if(Director::CurrentPage()->ClassName == 'CategoryPage')
        {
            $Category = Director::CurrentPage();
        }
        //Otherwise just grab the first category this product is in
        else
        {
            $Category = $this->Categories()->First();
        }  

        //Check we have a category then return the link
        if($Category)
        {
            return $Category->absoluteLink() . 'show/' . $this->URLSegment;      
        }

    }

    //Return the Title as a menu title
    public function MenuTitle()
    {
        return $this->Title;
    }

    function canView() {
        return true;
    }

    public function LinkingMode()   
    {
        //Check that we have a controller to work with and that it is a StaffPage
        if(Controller::CurrentPage() && Controller::CurrentPage()->ClassName == 'CategoryPage')
        {
            //check that the action is 'show' and that we have a StaffMember to work with
            if(Controller::CurrentPage()->getAction() == 'show' && $Product = Controller::CurrentPage()->getCurrentProduct())
            {
                //If the current StaffMember is the same as this return 'current' class
                return ($Product->ID == $this->ID) ? 'current' : 'link';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my CategoryPage.php

```php
<?php

class CategoryPage extends Page
{

    static $has_one = array(
        'CategoryBanner' => 'Image',
        'Photo' => 'Image'  
    );

    static $many_many = array(     
        'Products' => 'Product'
    );

    static $allowed_children = array(
        'none' => 'none'
    );

    function getCMSFields()
    {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();       
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Content.Images", new ImageField('Photo'));
        //Banner Images
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Content.Banner", new ImageField('CategoryBanner', 'Banner', Null, Null, Null, 'Uploads/category_banners'));

        return $fields;
    }  

    //important for sidebar showing, this is sitetree stuff - relationship between categories and products 20012012
    public function onBeforeDelete()
    {
        $CurrentVal = $this->get_enforce_strict_hierarchy();
        $this->set_enforce_strict_hierarchy(false);

        parent::onBeforeDelete();

        $this->set_enforce_strict_hierarchy($CurrentVal);
    }  

    public function Children(){
        return $this->Products();
    }
    //added this on 03022011 for the parent page to show on Categories in admin
    function CheckboxSummary(){ 
        return $this->Parent()->Title . ' - ' . $this->Title;
    }
}

class CategoryPage_Controller extends Page_Controller
{

    static $allowed_actions = array(
        'show'
    );

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        Requirements::css('themes/tutorial/css/products.css');

        //added this to make the gallery js work 10012012
        Requirements::set_write_js_to_body(false); 

        Requirements::javascript("mysite/javascript/jquery-1.4.2.min.js");                Requirements::javascript("mysite/javascript/jquery.cycle.lite.min.js");
        Requirements::javascript("mysite/javascript/toggle_menu.js");           
    }

    //Return the list of products for this category
    public function getProductsList()
    {
        return $this->Products(Null, 'Price ASC');
    }

    //Get's the current product from the URL, if any
    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {
        $Params = $this->getURLParams();
        $URLSegment = Convert::raw2sql($Params['ID']);

        if($URLSegment && $Product = DataObject::get_one('Product', "URLSegment = '" . $URLSegment . "'"))
        {      
            return $Product;
        }
    }

    //Shows the Product detail page
    function show()
    {
        //Get the Product
        if($Product = $this->getCurrentProduct())
        {
            $Data = array(
                'Product' => $Product,
                'MetaTitle' => $Product->Title
            );

            //return our $Data array to use, rendering with the ProductPage.ss template
            return $this->customise($Data)->renderWith(array('ProductPage', 'Page'));        
        }
        else //Product not found
        {
            return $this->httpError(404, 'Sorry that product could not be found');
        }
    }

    //Generate out custom breadcrumbs
    public function Breadcrumbs() {

        //Get the default breadcrumbs
        $Breadcrumbs = parent::Breadcrumbs();

        if($Product = $this->getCurrentProduct())
        {
            //Explode them into their individual parts
            $Parts = explode(SiteTree::$breadcrumbs_delimiter, $Breadcrumbs);

            //Count the parts
            $NumOfParts = count($Parts);

            //Change the last item to a link instead of just text
            $Parts[$NumOfParts-1] = ('<a href="' . $this->Link() . '">' . $Parts[$NumOfParts-1] . '</a>');

            //Add our extra piece on the end
            $Parts[$NumOfParts] = $Product->Title;

            //Return the imploded array
            $Breadcrumbs = implode(SiteTree::$breadcrumbs_delimiter, $Parts);          
        }

        return $Breadcrumbs;
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing any serious search stuff, the built-in search functionality (based on MySQL MyISAM) is not ideal. I'd suggest to use Solr or Sphinx, integrated into SilverStripe with https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-sphinx or https://github.com/nyeholt/silverstripe-solr (I'd start off with the first one). This will also index DAOs.

Comment: Hi Xeraa, very sorry for late reply &thanks very much for replying. I don't need a full on search function, the main purpose is to search products through the dataobject, and some info on the site. Do you think Sphinx is still the way to go? I've never done this before, do you have some links on how to start please? Also I see people suggested this http://www.silverstripe.org/all-other-modules/show/6641?start=24 but I'm having problems on implementing it. What directions would you give to me who is not highly experienced in the field? Thank you very much, sorry again for the delay. Thanks :)

Comment: I assume you mean http://www.silverstripe.org/all-other-modules/show/6641?start=24#post290089? Are you working with 2.4 or on the upcoming 3? In version 3 the default DB engine will switch to InnoDB which doesn't support fulltext search. You can switch back to MyISAM, but IMHO that's not the way to go.
I'd use https://github.com/nyeholt/silverstripe-solr - for the documentation get started with https://github.com/nyeholt/silverstripe-solr/wiki. I haven't really used that module myself, so I can't point to any more specific helpers. But it's IMHO the best and most future-proof approach :)

Comment: Thanks Xeraa for the follow ups, I'm using 2.4, so I presume I could give http://www.silverstripe.org/all-other-modules/show/6641?start=24#post290089 a try? Also thanks for the suggestion on solr, I am a bit scared of alter the server by using solr, also I'm developing on wamp at the mo. However I will give what you suggested a try, and let you know how I go later. Thank you very much for your help!